# Subsonic retuns me a menucollection object how do i map it to asp.net menu control

Tags: asp.net, subsonic

MenuCollection muc = new MenuCollection();
        muc.Load(SPs.UspGetUserMenu(Context.User.Identity.Name).GetReader());

how do i map it to the menu control in Asp.net

Answer (score 0):

If the menu control has a datasource property:

```
MenuCollection muc = new MenuCollection();
muc.Load(SPs.UspGetUserMenu(Context.User.Identity.Name).GetReader());
MyMenu.DataSource = muc;
MyMenu.DataBind();
```

EDIT: My idea was wrong. You can't just pass a subsonic collection to a menu datasource.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427097/binding-asp-net-menu-control-to-a-collection) related question shows that you need to implement the [IHierarchyData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.ihierarchydata.aspx) interface.